# merge two lists within a object conditionally

Tags: json, jq

Hellow jq experts!

I'm a jq learner and have a json obect composed lists as follows:

```
{
  "image_files": [
    {
      "id": "img_0001",
      "width": 32,
      "heigt": 32,
      "file_name": "img_0001.png"
    },
    {
      "id": "img_0002",
      "width": 128,
      "heigt": 32,
      "file_name": "img_0002.png"
    },
    {
      "id": "img_0003",
      "width": 32,
      "heigt": 32,
      "file_name": "img_0003.png"
    },
    {
      "id": "img_0004",
      "width": 160,
      "heigt": 32,
      "file_name": "img_0004.png"
    }
  ],
  "annotations": [
    {
      "id": "ann_0001",
      "image_id": "img_0001",
      "label": "A",
      "attributes": {
        "type": "letter",
        "augmented": false
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "ann_0002",
      "image_id": "img_0002",
      "label": "Good",
      "attributes": {
        "type": "word",
        "augmented": false
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "ann_0003",
      "image_id": "img_0003",
      "label": "C",
      "attributes": {
        "type": "letter",
        "augmented": false
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "ann_0004",
      "image_id": "img_0004",
      "label": "Hello",
      "attributes": {
        "type": "word",
        "augmented": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- `image_id` in the `annotations` list are foreign key referencing the `id` in the `image_files` list.

I want to join `image_files` and `annotations` with condition of `annotations.attribute.type == "letter"`.

Expecting following ouptut:

```
{
  "letter_image_files_with_label": [
    {
      "id": "img_0001",
      "width": 32,
      "heigt": 32,
      "file_name": "img_0001.png",
      "label": "A"
    },
    {
      "id": "img_0003",
      "width": 32,
      "heigt": 32,
      "file_name": "img_0003.png",
      "label": "C"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I produce above result from the json data input?
`join` explained in jq manual does not seem to use this kind task. 
Is there a way for this? Please show me the rope.

Thanks for your generous reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing `image_files` with `id`s makes this pretty trivial.

```
INDEX(.image_files[]; .id) as $imgs | [
  .annotations[]
  | select(.attributes.type == "letter")
  | $imgs[.image_id] + {label: .label}
]
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/eCpRdqSkXq)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. You saved me.  
Great !! very neat solution!

Comment: @ocuz ismail, Where did you get documentation on INDEX function?  
I could not find INDEX in man page of jq or jq manual.
Is there good tutorial for jq with practical examples?

Comment: @Hongsoog: `INDEX` is available from jq-1.6 onwards. In the official documentation click on the jq 1.6 manual  - https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/

Comment: @Inian, thanks for your suggestion. 
However, the explation on index in jq manual seems  too short to derive oguz ismail's solution. Who can imagine the usage like oguz ismail's solution with such short description on function ?

Comment: @oguz ismail,  It's very kind of you.
What should I do in order to merge image_files list and annotations list with following condition : annotations.attribues.type == "word" AND annotations.label's length == 4 I love your answer at online demo!!

Comment: You haven't accepted the above as the right answer but you moved on to ask a different one? You should credit the answerer with an upvote and accept to give them due credit.  See What should I do when someone answers my question? and What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"? in the help center

Comment: @oguz ismail, 
thanks for your answer again. Stii, I have no idea where\how  to put ```length``` builtin and how to make joint condition within ```select``` builtin.

Comment: @Inian, thanks for your advice. please forgive my ignorance on usage of stackoverflow. I did not recognize it. I will examine 
What should I do when someone answers my question? and What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"? in the help center

Comment: @oguz ismail, as your adivce, I tried with ```'INDEX(.image_files[]; .id) as $imgs | [ .annotations[] | select(.attributes.type == "word" and .attributes.label.length == 4) | $imgs[.image_id] + {label: .label} ]'``` but it produce ```[]```.  
Also tried with ```'INDEX(.image_files[]; .id) as $imgs | [ .annotations[] | select(.attributes.type == "word" and length(.attributes.label) == 4) | $imgs[.image_id] + {label: .label} ]'``` but got compile error this time. What's wrong with my code snippet?  I cannot figure out the problem.

Comment: @oguz ismail and @Inian, I tried with index as follows: 

```'INDEX(.image_files[]; .id) as $imgs | [ .annotations[] | select(.attributes.type == "word") |  select(.label | length | . ==4)  ]'``` 

and finally get the desired result.

I did forget the fact that most of things in jq are filter. I am still clumsy with jq style pipe line usage but gradually acquainted with it. 
Thanks for @oguz ismail for kind explanation and @Inian for pointing out etiquette on asking and upvoteing.

Comment: for who search final answer;
```'INDEX(.image_files[]; .id) as $imgs | [ .annotations[] | select(.attributes.type == "word") |  select(.label | length | . ==4)  | $imgs[.image_id] + {label:.label} ]'```