# merge two lists within a object with joint condition including length check

Tags: merge, conditional-statements, jq

Hello jq users and experts,

FYI, this question is related to [merge two lists within a object conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60967575/merge-two-lists-within-a-object-conditionally). But current question is merge with two lists withn joint condition including length check.

For the json data as follows:

```
{
  "image_files": [
    {
      "id": "img_0001",
      "width": 32,
      "heigt": 32,
      "file_name": "img_0001.png"
    },
    {
      "id": "img_0002",
      "width": 128,
      "heigt": 32,
      "file_name": "img_0002.png"
    },
    {
      "id": "img_0003",
      "width": 32,
      "heigt": 32,
      "file_name": "img_0003.png"
    },
    {
      "id": "img_0004",
      "width": 160,
      "heigt": 32,
      "file_name": "img_0004.png"
    }
  ],
  "annotations": [
    {
      "id": "ann_0001",
      "image_id": "img_0001",
      "label": "A",
      "attributes": {
        "type": "letter",
        "augmented": false
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "ann_0002",
      "image_id": "img_0002",
      "label": "Good",
      "attributes": {
        "type": "word",
        "augmented": false
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "ann_0003",
      "image_id": "img_0003",
      "label": "C",
      "attributes": {
        "type": "letter",
        "augmented": false
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "ann_0004",
      "image_id": "img_0004",
      "label": "Hello",
      "attributes": {
        "type": "word",
        "augmented": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- `image_id` in the `annotations` list is a kind of foreign key referencing the `id` in the `image_files` list.

My question is how to join `image_files` and `annotations` with joint condition of

- annotations.attributes.type == "word" AND
- annotations.label' length == 4.

The final result should be as follows:

```
{
  "four_letter_word_image_files_with_label": [
    {
      "id": "img_0002",
      "width": 128,
      "heigt": 32,
      "file_name": "img_0004.png"
      "label": "Good"
    }
  ]
}

How can I produce above result from the json data input?

Thanks for your reading.
```

Comment: your condition is somewhat unclear: a) there's no key `text` in `annotations.attributes`, b) if you meant `type` to be of size 4 then the condition is superfluous, because `type == "word"` is always the size of 4. Could you fix your requirement?

Comment: @Dmitry, it my mistake. I mean to ```annotations.label``` instead of ```annotations.attribute.text```. I corrected the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function to get you started.  You can extend it to meet your needs.

```
def Hongsoog:
  def makemap: reduce .annotations[] as $item ({}; .[$item.image_id]=$item) ;
  def join:    makemap as $idx | [ .image_files[] | { i:., a: $idx[.id] } ] ;
  def isword:  .a.attributes.type == "word" ;
  def islen4:  .a.label | length == 4 ;
  def format:  .i.label = .a.label | .i ; 
  def result:  [ join[] | select(isword and islen4) | format ];
  {
    "four_letter_word_image_files_with_label": result
  };

Hongsoog
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVPBbpwwEL3zFSPUQyKtrA2gqmK1h6qH5h8QQk48sE6NvQWjTbTh27e2MRuSULSRUpUDkmfevPc843n4fToxLOFWyapVqkoDAHuu6S@s6T6FBll3j0ColEpTzZVssxxoC1@4xhqujv0GSOYOhNe0woKzfOvO17DxbA@KyxTM52mHevYIz5CBLyu5QEv9DEfgKVkBTR0mI4YQesjPbLw9qIYZPkIJ1brhd53GluinPcJ2C6HNhhO0QJkMaEHvUBgFE6n0zoKTM65UTU21xXGP205LCIcNeGiDbScsNHM3c6ZbFHivrwZvQCXzwtcmN1BDbqWOge1DWKquKQRqjU1hK4pJE4oD17vCCYepFzNV/SYIxjGdTpYnnBQZZOaoBwGbZCZmIFWxXq9vwtUYP3CmdyYVR@fQDnmlX4csaSFpjVMSspdV6BD9akEsei92E337qFp0oVr8GVeLLxRLZq72df1RtWSiZv65BYeTDfvbMA3kzTDHlZsf9fiGwu8vsZeNMYmR38Tt@ljo8CjPeFvRVTVKjVakpKJFn@oX2uWdRotOoxmnP5Vil5t1q/45VuNFq/GM1R//qanJotNkxuktCqH@WVftCw76Pw)

Comment: thanks I try it.  It seems deserve to study it for further understand of jq

Comment: I tried with index as follows: ```'INDEX(.image_files[]; .id) as $imgs | [ .annotations[] | select(.attributes.type == "word") |  select(.label | length | . ==4)  ]'``` and get the desired result.

Comment: for who search final answer;
```'INDEX(.image_files[]; .id) as $imgs | [ .annotations[] | select(.attributes.type == "word") |  select(.label | length | . ==4)  | $imgs[.image_id] + {label:.label} ]'```

main point is most of things are filter in jq. hence you should be familiar with pipe line usage and the current input ```.``` concept in each piple line stage. Cheers...